# Intentionally freezing Windows for a second

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I'm currently debugging a small problem in a software that happened when the Computer froze for a moment (I was rummaging around, deleting files etc. and the OS just froze momentarily).

I am now trying to freeze the Computer intentionally for a second or so, but it's harder than I thought. Just hogging the CPU with a bunch of hard-working threads doesn't do it as the OS obviously still handles the scheduling fine.

Can someone name a way to induce such a system-wide short freeze of all OS activity? Is there a specific resource I can hog in a software or combination thereof?

It's quite hard to google, as anyone is trying to solve something like that, not induce it. :-)

OS is Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit.

Comment: I would focus more on trying to resolve the issue, via Windows updates and driver updates. I would also run a https://www.memtest86.com/ on your RAM and maybe Prime95 on your CPU to soak-test it.

Comment: Look in Resource Monitor (Security and Maintenance) and see what Stopped Working errors you have.

Comment: "system freeze" is quite a vague thing (more like a symptom / observation).

Comment: The fact that Windows froze for a moment is not the problem. I am trying to diagnose the behavior of a running program of mine while that short freeze occured and therefore want to reproduce it. @TomYan true. It's hard to describe more clearly than a short hiccup that happens sometimes. I guess the OS doesn't allocate cpu time to the process. If I knew why, I couldtry to replicate that.that's the Question. I could try a forkbomb but I can't recover from that ;-)

Comment: Did you try Reliability History?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of freezing the whole system I reverted to suspending the individual process by suspending the processes threads for short periods of time in order to simulate the system freezing for a moment.